# Javascript / jQuery: How to prevent active input field from being changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I prevent the user to change the value in an input field (which contains a certain value to be copied into the clipboard) without using disabled="true"? The text should be selected once the user clicks in the field (that's working already) but entering anything should have no effect.

Thanks

```
jQuery('input.autoselect[value]').focus(function() { jQuery(this).select(); });
```

Comment: So you have an input, an element designed entirely to get data from the user and put it into the system, as an output? And now you are trying to work around the problem of inputs being designed to accept input? I'd fix the markup so you aren't using an input solely for output.

Comment: check out youtube, they are doing the same. I just want to provide a shortlink which the user should be able to copy into the clipboard easily. What's wrong with that??? Input fields have some advantages here. Just try to be productive!

Comment: I agree with criscrasp here. Inputs definitely do have advantages over normal text for outputting. And as criscrasp says, youtube does it too. I think it is a sensible technique.

Comment: *Outputting data that should be easily copyable that is.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**readonly** in the html of the input is all you need to prevent the user from editing the input.

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" value="You can't edit me!"/>
```

Comment: haha, that's so emberassing... You're right, I only tried disabled but not readonly, totaly forgot about it! Thanks!

Comment: +1 I'm an idiot too. :-) I read "without using disabled" and thought "without using attributes".

Comment: no problem! I just read the question (3 times) and was confused what the trick was. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
var val = jQuery('input.autoselect[value]').val();
jQuery('input.autoselect[value]').change( function(){
   jQuery(this).val(val);
});
```

Or possibly (not sure)

```
jQuery('input.autoselect[value]').keydown(function(){
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the second version works but also prevents the user from copying the content (because CMD+C doesn't work either), with the first version I have the problem that it should work for more than 1 field on a page. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Pim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079300/javascript-jquery-how-to-prevent-active-input-field-from-being-changed/1079319#1079319), how about this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("input.readonly").each(function(){
           jQuery(this).attr("savedVal", jQuery(this).val());
    });

    jQuery("input.readonly").change(function(){
           jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).attr("savedVal"));
    });

});
```

(completely untested, but it demonstrates the idea...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.getElementById("newval").readOnly = true;
</script>
```

Watch for the capital "O" in readonly...